# Using forkFinally with WriterT

Tags: haskell

I have a timer function that takes a time to wait for and a starting time and returns the current UTCTime when it ends:

```
runTimer :: NominalDiffTime -> UTCTime -> IO UTCTime
```

I'd like to run this timer function in a separate thread, because I want to simultaneously be able to capture input from the user. In this main loop I also use a WriterT monad transformer to log events. I also want to log an event when the timer ends normally, so I've tried using forkFinally:

```
type Log = [Entry]           
data Entry = Entry {
      _etype :: EntryType    
    , _etime :: UTCTime      
} deriving Show

data EntryType = Start | End | Pause | Quit deriving Show

type Program = WriterT Log IO

loop :: Maybe ThreadId -> Program ()
loop timerId = do
  liftIO $ putStr ">"
  x <- liftIO $ getChar      
  now <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
  case x of
    'q' -> do
            liftIO $ putStrLn "\n Quitting..."
            tell [Entry Quit now]
            -- Kill the timer thread if there is one.
            maybe (return ()) (liftIO . killThread) timerId
            liftIO $ putStrLn "\n Quit."
    's' -> case timerId of
             Just _ -> do
                 liftIO $ putStrLn "Timer already started!"
                 loop timerId
             Nothing -> do
                 -- Start a timer in a new thread.
                 tell [Entry Start now]
                 timerId' <- liftIO $ forkFinally (runTimer 5 now) eHandler
                 -- Call the main loop with the timer thread id.
                 loop (Just timerId')
    _   -> do
            liftIO $ putChar x
            loop timerId                       

eHandler :: (Show a, Exception e) => Either e a -> IO ()
eHandler (Left x) = throw x  
eHandler (Right x) = do
  putStrLn $ show x

eHandler' :: (Exception t) => Either t UTCTime -> WriterT Log IO ()
eHandler' (Left x) = throw x
eHandler' (Right t) = do
  tell [Entry End t]
```

This code works when using forkFinally with eHandler. But how can I get it to work with eHandler', so that I can log when the timer finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert a WriterT monad to an IO monad, something like this:

```
wrapWriterT::WriterT a IO c->IO c
wrapWriterT writer = do
  (result, log) <- runWriterT writer
  <do something with the log, like send it to a file>
  return result
```

and then use it like this:

```
timerId' <- liftIO $ forkFinally (runTimer 5 now) (wrapWriterT  . eHandler')
```

What is happening here?  Remember, the `Writer` monad is used to pass an extra string around, that can be appended to, like a log.  The `IO` monad is used for, well....  `IO`.  `forkFinally` needs type `IO()`, but the `WriterT` is for both `IO` *and* also returns a log.  `forkFinally` doesn't know what to do with this log, but if you wrap it in a function to extract the log and do something with it, then you are left with simply an `IO` monad, which `forkFinally` knows how to handle.

---

I do want to ask though....  The standard timer functions in `Control.Concurrent` are nonblocking (you hand it a function of type IO(), and it returns, with the understanding that it will be done later).  What are you doing that needs explicit threads?

Comment: runTimer just loops until the specified time has passed (with threadDelay of a second), printing a countdown. But I want to capture input (what the loop function does) while the timer is running, and I couldn't figure out how to do that without running runTimer in a separate thread.

Comment: If you use the functions in Control.Concurrent, you won't need to loop.  With looping, you either eat cpu or lose accuracy if you put in a small delay to cut down on cpu processing.  Also, the code will be smaller using the functions in Control.Concurrent.  Because the functions in Control.Concurrent are nonblocking, you can check for keypresses after the function is set.  (internally, the Control.Concurrent stuff might use threads also, but you don't have to concern yourself with that).